# I wrote this command "sudo npm install --save-dev grafana/grafana-sdk-mocks", I am getting this error

Tags: grafana

[sudo] password for mayukh: 
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! fatal: failed to stat '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-02bd6ef9': Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-28T08_58_16_327Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

When doing `npm install` for your project you shouldn't have to run it as the superuser.

`sudo` is normally use with the `-g` flag (global) of `npm install`.

Looking at the error message, it seems like whichever process that is running the git `submodule` program is having issue in creating files in the `/root/.npm/...` directory. It is probably worth noting that when you run the `sudo` command, while the `npm install` program is ran with `root` privilege but it could be forking other independent processes (that is non-root) to to execute its subprograms. In this case the `submodule`. Hence the permission issue.

I guess the best and also the most correct solution would be to do `npm install` without `sudo`.

If you really need to run it as `sudo` for whatever reason. Then you should elevate yourself as root (`sudo -i) before doing npm install.